# Program for Moving Average from Gekko Quant

Tags: r, moving-average

I am trying to implement the program for the moving average rule from Gekko Quant - http://gekkoquant.com/2012/08/29/parameter-optimisation-backtesting-part-2/

However I keep getting the same error - Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

I have slightly modified the code to match my data and is as follows;

```
TradingStrategy <- function(mktdata,mavga_period,mavgb_period){

runName <- paste("MAVGa",mavga_period,".b",mavgb_period,sep="")
print(paste("Running Strategy: ",runName))

returns <- diff(log(ES$Close))

mavga <- SMA(ES$Close),1=mavga_period)
mavgb <- SMA(ES$Close),5=mavgb_period)

signal <- mavga / mavgb

signal <- apply(signal,1,function (x) { if(is.na(x)){ return (0) } else { if(x>1){return (1)} else {return (-1)}}})

tradingreturns <- signal * returns
colnames(tradingreturns) <- runName

return (tradingreturns)
}
```

My data is in the dataframe "ES" in column "Close". Some example data would be;

```
50
51
52
59
54
49
50
50
40
45
46
50
51
52
59
54
49
50
50
40
45
46
```

Comment: The following two lines are wrong `mavga <- SMA(ES$Close),1=mavga_period); mavgb <- SMA(ES$Close),5=mavgb_period)`.

Comment: Thanks but what is wrong with the two lines? The moving average period for the mavga_period is 1 and the moving average period for the mavgb_period is 5.

Comment: There is something wrong with the number of parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looking at the last error, you should be looking at the first error, fixing it and going to the next first error:

```
 mavga <- SMA(ES$Close),1=mavga_period)
Error: unexpected ',' in:
```

You finished the function call to `SMA` with the first closing-paren:

```
  mavga <- SMA(ES$Close),1=mavga_period)
                    here^
```

The next line has the same syntactic error. If you take them out, you expose a semantic error when you attempt to assign something to the number `1`. I was  guessing the original was the letter `"l"` and the font being used didn't make that clear. But looking at the original you are not faithfully copying shows valid code:

```
 #Calculate the moving averages
  mavga <- SMA(Op(mktdata),n=mavga_period)
  mavgb <- SMA(Op(mktdata),n=mavgb_period)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I understand the SMA and error because of the closed parenthesis.  I have copied the code but just changed the data they have to my data (ES data frame with Close the column) and wanted the two moving average periods to be 1 and 5.  Is that not what the following line of the code is for;

    #Calculate the moving averages
    mavga <- SMA(Op(mktdata),n=mavga_period)
    mavgb <- SMA(Op(mktdata),n=mavgb_period)

Does the n not just change because the manga_period stands for the moving average period a and mavgb_period stands for moving average period b?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I understand the SMA and error because of the closed parenthesis.  I have copied the code but just changed the data they have to my data (ES data frame with Close the column) and wanted the two moving average periods to be 1 and 5.  Is that not what the following line of the code is for;

    #Calculate the moving averages
    mavga <- SMA(Op(mktdata),n=mavga_period)
    mavgb <- SMA(Op(mktdata),n=mavgb_period)

Does the n not just change because the manga_period stands for the moving average period a and mavgb_period stands for moving average period b?

Comment: Assignment with the "=" operator is always `symbol = value`. And `1` cannot be a symbol. I have no idea that the "n" stood for. I only know that you cannot assign a new value to the number `1`. I called that a semantic error, but it's really a syntactic error as well.

Answer (score 0):

The cited blog post is no longer available. However, I infer that you want something like this:

```r
library(tidyquant)

TradingStrategy <- function(mktdata, mavga_period, mavgb_period) {
  returns <- c(NA, diff(log(mktdata$Close)))
  
  mavga <- SMA(mktdata$Close, mavga_period)
  mavgb <- SMA(mktdata$Close, mavgb_period)
  
  signal <- mavga / mavgb
  signal <- ifelse(is.na(signal), 0, ifelse(signal > 1, 1, -1))

  data.frame(return = signal * returns)
}
```

Create some dummy data and test.

```r
data <- tribble(
  ~Close,
  50,
  51,
  52,
  59,
  54,
  49,
  50,
  50,
  40,
  45,
  46,
  50,
  51,
  52,
  59,
  54,
  49,
  50,
  50,
  40,
  45,
  46
)

TradingStrategy(data, 1, 5)
```

Output:

```
        return
1           NA
2   0.00000000
3   0.00000000
4   0.00000000
5  -0.08855340
6   0.09716375
7  -0.02020271
8   0.00000000
9   0.22314355
10 -0.11778304
11 -0.02197891
12  0.08338161
13  0.01980263
14  0.01941809
15  0.12629373
16 -0.08855340
17  0.09716375
18 -0.02020271
19  0.00000000
20  0.22314355
21 -0.11778304
22 -0.02197891
```

You might want to tweak the column name.